# Select inline elements without text siblings

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I need to select inline HTML elements that are the only thing inside their parent element - that is, there is no text or other inline elements before or after them.

```
<p><img src="foo.jpg"></p><!-- This should be selected -->
<p>Hello world! <img src="bar.jpg"></p><!-- This should not -->
```

Any way to do this with CSS or jQuery? I've tried `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` but they match both of these elements.

Comment: Certainly not with CSS.

Comment: Keeping what as target point?? `p` tags??

Comment: Do whitespace nodes count?

Comment: Whitespace nodes do not count. Either the `p` tags or the element inside are ok for my needs since I need to do some extra processing for the elements and it's trivial to derive one from the other with JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.children()` will be the selected children you desire. You could potentially add these to an array if you want to use them for later or just print them using `console.log()`

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
        $(this).children();
    }
});
```

As pointed out, if an `<a>` was present with text inside it (i.e. `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` then the code above will not work. If you are in that following situation where it's children have it's own text, use `val()` in the condition instead:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).children();
    }
});
```

Comment: Also use `trim()` or `$.trim()` to avoid whitespace

Comment: This works like a charm after I added a `.trim()` to remove any whitespace from the text content. Thank you!

Comment: There is one more condition. The 'child' should be only one. It shouldn't have siblings

Comment: This would also select two images.

Comment: I don't know if @Kaivosukeltaja want to select another element, not only images, but with this code you can't select an element with text inside like a link for example.

Comment: @blonfu I have added an alternative solution if this is the case for OP

Comment: @wmash val() don't work for me apart from input, textarea and other form elements

Comment: @blonfu do you mean `input`, `textarea` as the parent element or the child?

Comment: doesn't matter. `val()` only works with form elements. I can't get the text of an element with `val()`

Comment: @blonfu are you attempting to get the text of a `textarea` then? Note that `input` does not **have** to be wrapped in a from to be valid HTML. Also, `textarea` does not have a `val()` attribute, although, if you call `.val()` on it, it should return the text between it's tags. Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/za0wbz3o/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114940/discussion-between-blonfu-and-wmash).

Answer (score 1):

One would have to check if child node is single and its [nodeType](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodetype.asp). jQuery's [contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method will get all child nodes including text and comments.

Below is an example script, which will mark single nodes, as well as paragraphs which contain single nodes:

```js
var notAcceptableNodeTypes = [3, 4, 8];
$('p').filter(function() {
    var nodes = $(this).contents();
    var isSingle = nodes.length==1 && $.inArray(nodes[0].nodeType, notAcceptableNodeTypes) == -1;
    if( isSingle ) nodes.addClass('is-single');
    return isSingle;
}).addClass('no-text');
```

```css
.no-text {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.is-single {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75"></p>
<p>Hello world! <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75"></p>
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75"><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75"></p>
<p>Hello world!</p>
<p><!-- COMMENT --><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75"></p>
```

Also on [Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/e6aezn53/).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can check the length of the `contents()` of the element:

```
var $p = $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).contents().length == 1;
});
```

Note though that this can be broken by whitespace. You would need to keep the parent and child elements on the same line in code with no whitespace separating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little combination of CSS and JavaScript (jQuery here for brevity).

```
var children = $(":only-child").filter(function() {
    return !this.previousSibling && !this.nextSibling;
});
```

The `:only-child` selector begins the search with elements that have no element siblings. Then `previous/nextSibling` would return a text node if there is one, or `null` if not. If both sides are `null`, then there are no text node siblings, so the element is truly alone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:first` for getting first p tag from multiple:

```
$("p:first)
```